# Multiple server instances by using Hapi.js framework

Tags: javascript, plugins, hapi.js

I'm approaching to this framework for node.js for several reasons. Simplicity, great modularity and a fast configuration out of the box. I have soon encountered the concept of Pack which I have never seen during my experience in the learning of express.js framework. From the official guide the following example:

```
var Good = require('good');

server.pack.register(Good, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; // something bad happened loading the plugin
    }

    server.start(function () {
        server.log('info', 'Server running at: ' + server.info.uri);
    });
});
```

They says about Pack:

> Packs are a way for hapi to combine multiple servers into a single
>   unit, and are designed to give a unified interface when working with
>   plugins.

This concept is weird for me. How many times do we work with different servers in a project? In addition is not clear for me whether I should call pack every time to register a plugins in hapi.

**Update:** This is pre v8 api code, the way to register a plugin has been changed. (call `register` directly on the `server`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This concept is  weird for me. How many times do we work with different servers in a project?

One example is when you have an api and a web server. These are usually developed separately, often in separate repositories. You could then create a third project which combines these plugins:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var manifest = {
  servers: [
    {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8000,
      options: {
        labels: 'api',
        cors: true
      }
    },
    {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8001,
      options: {
        labels: 'web'
      }
    }
  ],
  plugins: {
    './example-api': [{select: 'api'}],
    './example-web': [{select: 'web'}]
  }
};

Hapi.Pack.compose(manifest, function(err, pack) {
  pack.start();
});
```

> In addition is not clear for me whether I should call ever time pack to register a plugins in hapi.

Yes, you need to call [`pack.register()`](http://hapijs.com/api#packregisterplugins-options-callback) when you want to register a plugin. However you can register more plugins at once:

```
plugin.register([
  require('crumb'),
  require('hapi-auth-cookie')
], function (err) {
  // Error handling
}
```

Comment: In the case I create different servers, I should start it by calling the command pack.start(), shouldn't I?

Answer (score 2):

Visit Link: http://cronj.com/blog/hapi-mongoose

Sample Project which can help you Repo Link: https://github.com/gauravgupta90/Hapi-Mongoose-Angular

For hapi version earlier than 8.x

```
var server = Hapi.createServer(host, port, {
    cors: true
});

server.start(function() {
    console.log('Server started ', server.info.uri);
});
```

For hapi new version

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: app.config.server.port });
```

Answer (score 1):

`Hapi.Pack()` is no longer available in the newest versions of Hapi (8.x).  They have pulled the functionality out into a small library called Glue.  You can find it here: https://github.com/hapijs/glue.  It works exactly how `Hapi.Pack()` used to.

Answer (score 1):

By default, hapi supports multiple connections and you can customize them individually, like [installing plugins only for a selected server (like API only)](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-how-to-register-plugins-for-a-selected-server-instance).

You can instantiate and kick off multiple connection like this:

```
const hapi = require('hapi');  
const port = 3000;  
const _ = require('lodash');

// Create hapi server instance
const server = new hapi.Server();

// add connection parameters
server.connection({  
    host: 'localhost',
    port: process.env.PORT || port
});

server.connection({  
    host: 'localhost',
    port: process.env.PORT + 1 || port + 1
});

// Start the server
server.start(function () {  
    // Log to the console the host and port info
    _.forEach(server.connections, function(connection) {
        console.log('Server started at: ' + connection.info.uri);
    });
});
```

Hope that helps.

If you need more details about that topic, you can find them within this tutorial on [how to run separate frontend and backend servers within a single project](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-how-to-run-separate-frontend-and-backend-servers-within-one-project)